# Huawei Matebook X wifi not working

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers, intel-core-i7, wifi-driver

I have been using the Huawei matebook X laptop for some months now since I bought it from Amazon.

The wifi has suddenly stopped working. 
Intel wireless 9560 cannot work on my machine anymore. I have uninstalled and installed  the drivers multiple times, reinstalled the windows 10, updated the BIOS but my problem has not been sorted out.

Please help.

Comment: Did you try to install the driver from the [Huawei page](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/laptops/matebook-x/)?

Comment: Yes, I have but does not change anything.

Comment: It should be under warranty, contact Huawei Support.